# What determines a login shell's default trap handlers?

Tags: shell, ssh, trap

I have a linux box that when I login with ssh, both the keystroke `Ctrl-C` and manually sending `SIGINT` will directly terminates the session.

```
λ> ssh root@rhel74
Last login: Sun Mar 18 21:08:02 2018 from 10.84.40.182
rhel74:~ # ^CConnection to rhel74 closed.
λ> ssh root@rhel74
Last login: Sun Mar 18 21:11:38 2018 from 10.84.40.182
rhel74:~ # ps -ef | grep bash
root     132203 132199  0 21:11 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash
root     132246 132203  0 21:11 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto bash
rhel74:~ # kill -2 132203
Connection to rhel74 closed.
```

`trap` shows that `SIGINT` is handled by `exit`. And if a separate shell is spawned, `SIGINT` will work as expected.

```
rhel74:~ # trap
trap -- 'exit' SIGINT
trap -- 'exit' SIGTERM
trap -- '' SIGTSTP
trap -- '' SIGTTIN
trap -- '' SIGTTOU
rhel74:~ # bash
rhel74:~ # trap
trap -- '' SIGTSTP
trap -- '' SIGTTIN
trap -- '' SIGTTOU
rhel74:~ # ^C
```

But what actually determines the default trap handlers for a shell? How to change the behaviour that `Ctrl-C` quits my ssh session?